# Converting Jasmine SpyObj Mock to Jest Mock

Tags: typescript, jestjs, angularfire2, ts-jest

I'm attempting to migrate my angular project tests from Jasmine to Jest. While attempting to mock the Angularfire firestore class using the TS-Jest mocked method I can't seem to get this right.

An example of how I have achieved this many times using jasmine's createSpyObj method.

```
describe('My Example', () => {
    let firestoreSpy: SpyObj<AngularFirestore>;
    let firestoreCollectionSpy: SpyObj<AngularFirestoreCollection>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        firestoreSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('firestoreSpy', ['collection']);
        firestoreCollectionSpy= jasmine.createSpyObj('firestoreCollectionSpy', ['snapshotChanges']);
        firestoreSpy.collection.and.returnValue(firestoreCollectionSpy);
    });

    it('My Test', () => {
        // Set the return value of the snapshotChanges method
        collectionSpy.snapshotChanges.and.returnValue(of());
    };
});
```

Trying to implement this using jest mocks I have tried.

```
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

describe('Jest Tests', () => {
  let firestoreMock; // I Want to be able to type this as well

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.mock('@angular/fire/firestore');
    firestoreMock = mocked(AngularFirestore, true);
  });

  it('My Test', () => {
    firestoreMock.collection.mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        snapshotChanges: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(of()),
      };
    });
  });
});
```

I've been getting an undefined value for collection which is very much a method of the class AngularFirestore

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'mockImplementation' of undefined
```

Any insights that can get me on the right track would be appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Specially this part: `==> // I Want to be able to type this as well`

Comment: @sebaferreras Sorry, I don't think I ever resolved this. If you find a work around/solution I would appreciate if you let me know. I'll be going back to this project in the near future.